# How to remove scrub/loading bar in HTML 5 video player

Tags: html, video, controls

I'm new to using HTML 5 for video and I have a project that the client requested to remove the scrub bar, so someone can't skip ahead to certain parts of the video. Is there a way this can be done? I know that on an iPhone there probably isn't any control over that because iOS adds its own when you're viewing it on full screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove the default controls individually, but you could remove all the controls and then implementing your own media control set using the Media API and simply not add a scrubber.

Answer (score 0):

To remove only scrub bar use this below code:

```
audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline,
video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {
    display: none;
}
```

To remove all controls from the video player using CSS (you can also remove controls attribute from the video tag to remove all controls):

```
audio::-webkit-media-controls,
video::-webkit-media-controls {
    display: none;
}
```